# how to highlight a custom list view on clicking of another view i.e Button

Tags: android, listview, background, highlight

I am displaying a *custom list view* and i want to traverse the list from the another button one for list down and one for list up,so here i am able to get the current selected item position so i am using-

```
list.setSelection(newpostion);
```

but i am not able to see the highlight to the given position. Here, *list* is being traversed properly but the user is not able to see on which list item currently he is. So please tell me how to highlight or change the background of a particular list item.

I tried with *selector* like with state change background but i.e not working for me. Please provide me any working solutions.

here is the code of list adapter-

```
package com.sho;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class list_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>
{
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items;
LayoutInflater mInflater ; 
Context context;
int layoutResourceId; 

public list_adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _list) 
{
        super(context, layoutResourceId, _list);
        this.layoutResourceId=layoutResourceId;
        this.items = _list;
        this.context=context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            if(row==null)
            {
                mInflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chapterdetails, parent, false);
                holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.chapterdata);


            }

            else
            {
                holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

            }

            row.setTag(holder);
            row.setId(position);

       HashMap<String,String>  map=items.get(position);
       holder.name.setText(map.get("DESCRIPTION"));
        return row;
}

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView name;
    ImageButton annotion,bookmark,edit;
}

}
```

code of the button from where i want traverse down the list ,here list name is ls-

```
View earliest=new View(MainActivity.this);

                if(postion<a1&&postion<=a1-2) 
                {
                     postion++;
                     earliest=ls.getRootView().findViewById(postion);
                        earliest.setBackground(null);




                     View v=new View(MainActivity.this); 
                    v=ls.getRootView().findViewById(postion); 
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    previous.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // your list
                    previous=v;
                     } } });
```

Comment: Are you able to focus on a listitem manually by clicking on it? That could indicate that the listitems are not focusable.

Comment: yes if i click it the selected background comes to that particular item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: 
After setting the `list.setSelection(newpostion);`

get that view like this

```
View v=list.getSelectedView();
```

then the same logic follows

Your code goes like this

Create a global Variable

```
View previous;
```

initialize it in the onCreate

```
previous=new View(this);



 traverse_listdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override 
public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
System.out.println("down"); 
int a1=list.getCount();

if(postion<a1&&postion<=a1-2) {
 postion++; list.setSelection(postion);
 View v1=new View(MainActivity.this); 
v1=list.getSelectedView(); 
v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
previous.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); // your list
previous=v1;
 } } });
```

---

Try this,

Create a drawable selector like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pause_button"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/play_button" />
</selector>
```

you can specify color or drawable of your choice.

create global variable like this

```
View previous;
```

initialize it

```
previious=new View(context);
```

When your listitem clicked use like this

```
yourlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long arg3) {
        previous.setSelected(false);                        
        view.setSelected(true);
        previous=view;

}
});
```

Comment: but how to do this selection of list item from a separate button and i am having customized list view

Comment: no the button is outside somewhere the list and from those buttons i have to traverse the list up and down

Comment: Sorry but I can't get you.. you mean button is not part of your listview.?

Comment: yaa button is not part of list view those buttons are seprate

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25517/discussion-between-pragnani-and-daniel)

Comment: Actually chat is blocked here in my company in case we can chat on gmail

Comment: @Daniel Now I got you..Sorry I have answer your question without reading it completely...check my edit

Comment: @Daniel you need initialize your previous view... And is this list.getSelectedView() returning null, post the stack trace

Comment: 03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):  at com.zhousho.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:170)
03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-04 17:50:28.806: E/AndroidRuntime(4744):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

Comment: i am using like- traverse_listdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("down");
    
    int a1=list.getCount();
    //previous.setActivated(true);
   
    if(postion<a1&&postion<=a1-2)
    {
     postion++;
     list.setSelection(postion);
     View v1=new View(MainActivity.this);
      v1=list.getSelectedView();
     v1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    
    
   }
  });

Comment: now the view is set to a particular color but only the view visible to the screen it only traverse those after that same error null pointer

Comment: 170 line is clicking event now i am getting view using- previous=list.getChildAt(postion); instead of  v1=list.getSelectedView();

Comment: @Daniel if it returns null then use list.getChildAt(position)

Comment: here using the -previous=list.getRootView().findViewById(postion); ,there the background is set but during traversing after some list item it again gives the error null pointer

Comment: @Daniel it will be useful for others if you can edit your question and post the answer

Comment: the way is this one only but i changed in adapter so that highlight comes properly

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to focusability. If you have a custom list view with focusable object in them, try to make them non-focusable.

```
aButtonInYourListView.Focusable = false;
aButtonInYourListView.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
```

Do this for all your buttons, imagebuttons in your ListViewAdapter. It can be done from xml as well but not for imagebutton from my experience. Do it in code to be on the safe side.

This should allow the ListViewItems to be focusable.

Comment: i already make the layout and the buttons which i am showing and giving to list adapter non focusable using these two property but still if i am trying to traverse the list from any another view that time i am not able to see which item is selected i.e no highlight ,no different background comes to that current selected item